# Using ARRAY_TO_STRING with integer array

Tags: google-bigquery

`ARRAY_TO_STRING()` works with string arrays but is not supported with integer arrays.

I have a repeated column that contains a list of IDs, I want to export this from a US dataset to an EU dataset. So far I'm using

`bq query --nouse_legacy_sql --allow_large_results --max_rows=100000000000 --format=csv < {sql_file} > {output_file}` but this does not work with nested columns as CSV does not support them.

Another option is exporting as json but I would need to convert this to newline JSON. I could use `jq` to convert this but it is not installed on the server by default.

Instead of that, I'm going down the path of flattening repeated columns before export. What I think I need to do is convert every element in the array to string and then use `ARRAY_TO_STRING()`. Am I going down the right path here?

I believe I want something similar to

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY((SELECT CAST(* AS STRING)), ';') FROM UNNEST(segments)) FROM my_table
```

but this gives me `Syntax error: Unexpected "*"` as it should. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(id AS STRING), ';') 
    FROM UNNEST(segments) id
  ) 
FROM `project.dataset.mytable`
```

Comment: Ah, aliasing the unnest was the missing piece. Thank you!

Comment: right. consider voting up and accept the answer if it helped :o)

Comment: btw, in addition to aliasing  - as you can see in my answer - you can directly generate needed string avoiding first creating array and then transform it to string

Comment: Indeed, very nice 